# PHP CURL - get response text

Tags: php, curl

I am making a CURL request to external site. In response I get a text message and a boolean. I want to format the message to be displayed in my site, but I cannot access the text. This is my request code:

```
$ch = curl_init();           
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'url goes here');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);           
$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

The response is "This is response textbool(true)" - it detects only the bool and I cannot access the text. Is there a way to access it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need set another option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```